# java - remove float leftovers elegantly

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

In brief - I am having a hard time with the float left overs
 (i.e. 10.00000123 instead of 10)

Here I go :

I need to generate list of floats with constant gap as follows 
(actually its a map , I need to retreive the object nut nevermind that)

List A: 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, ...
or
List B: 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, ...

every time I get a number and I round it to the neerest cell in the list.
lets say I get 0.051 to retreive a cell in list A - I return 0.05.
lets say I get 0.21 to retreive a cell in list B - I return 0.25.

So I started be doing this

```
float a = Math.round(Value / step) * step;
```

but than I get a lot of time 0.2500001  (float leftovers ) 
I need a smart way to round it .

Maybe by taking the number of digits after the dot and doing again

```
Math.round(Value / 100) * 100;?
```

Is there a smarter way? 
I tried doig this

```
        final float factor = Math.round(1 / step);
        final float value = (float) Math.round(value * factor) / factor;
```

but I sometimes have a list like this

List A: 10, 15 , 20, 25, 30, ...

and when I get 22 I retreive the cell of 20. 
the problem is that When I get a gap of 10

```
Math.round(1 / baseAssetStep)
```

returns 0 - and I get NaN

Comment: Is the rounding necessary? If printing them is the issue you can leave the floats as is and simply print with specific precision. For eg, `String.format("%.4f",2.142133);` will round to four places exactly...

Comment: use BigDecimal when u want exact numbers

Comment: rounding is a must. I will need to know how many fraction digits are there. Lets say I get o.25f . I need to get that it is 2 digits . but what if i get 0.25000001 ? \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, "these are not the numbers you're looking for."

Floating points are represented as *binary* fractional numbers, and some numbers that can be easily represented in base-10 (0.01, for instance) can't be represented with a finite number of binary digits. This is similar to how 1/3 is easy in base 3 (it's just 0.1), but requires an infinite number of digits in base 10 (0.333...).

If you tried to represent 1/3 with a finite number of digits in base 10, you'd get an approximation. Similarly, if you try to represent 1/10 with a finite number of digits in base 2 (which is what `float` and `double` do), you'll get an approximation, and similarly with 1/100. What you think is 0.01 in the code is actually a number that's very close, but not exactly equal to, 1/100.

There are many resources out there concerning floating points and the difficulty in working with them. http://floating-point-gui.de/ is a good place to start.

Comment: wow. a site dedicated for my question plus an xkcd reference to my question inside it. It's the truman show.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `float`.

---

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of *Primitive Data Types*:

> **float:** [...] This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the
>   [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead. Numbers and Strings covers
>   BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform.

Comment: wouldnt this slow down the system (because of string parsing)? can you give an example of its benefits? thanks

Comment: How many million times per second do you need to parse your numbers? Have you measured your code and found that this is a bottleneck? You should foremost be concerned with your code working *correctly* which is something you will most likely not achieve while using `float`s. Once your code is correct you can look at how to make it faster.

Comment: Bombe, 
A. I actually did measure my code. I just found that the MATH library takes a huge chunk of the running time (to be more precise math.round() eats up 35% of my thread). Thats why I am trying to use it as less as I can.
B. My code does work fine currently. I am in the tuning and fixsing part now.

Comment: 35% of what total time? you must also consider absolute values. for example 35% of 100 ms is not that much

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would use `double` or `long` instead as these have much more digits of accuracy.  If you really need to, use BigDecimal, but its pretty rare to find a real world situation where `double` or `long` would not do the job.

```
double d = 10.00000123;
double r = Math.round(d * 10000) / 10000.0;
```

or using long with fixed point precision.

```
long l = 100000; // the actual value * 10000
```

A common use case for fixed point precision is money.  Instead of using dollars with `double` use cents with `long` or even `int` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need a constant gap, so maybe try another solution. Take your gap, let's name it G. Draw a randow int - let's call it R, (if you know maximum number in your list you can draw it properly). Now the only thing to do would be R*G which will give you a number from your list - of course with some precision because this is inevitable using float - to print it just use format. You can also combine this with BigDecimal ;)

Comment: Nice solution. But I get 9.22 as an input. I need to figure out what is the R.

Comment: for a given list: 
0,2,4...28
R would be new Random().nextInt(28), if list would be shifted from 0:
4,8...32
R would be new Random().nextInt(28) + 4

if your doubt is what i think of